# Can not save .cer file to keychain

Tags: ios, certificate

I can not save a .cer file to my keychain. I see them being saved under system "certificates" but not under login "my certificates". Saving them under system it does not allow for me to create .p12 files. Anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove .cer certificate from keychain which installed under system certificates. Now select keys from left panel remove keys also for your certificate. Select My Certificates quit Keychain access. 
Restart your system.Now again try to install .cer file.

It worked for me.